# Why is my regex reverse in ng-pattern?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/II4RLMviSep3zFcgtcAv?p=preview

```
<form name="linkform">
  <input ng-model="myvar" type="url" ng-pattern="/[abcd]+/">
  <p>{{myvar}}</p>
  <p ng-show="linkform.$error.url">ERROR!</p>
</form>
```

In the example I expect it to match "abcdabcdabcd", but instead that is invalid, while "232r4t3trq" or anything other than [abcd] is valid.

I'm very confused. Basically the url validation by Angular is awful, so I was trying to make it better, but then I got stuck with weird behaviour by ng-pattern.
(hmmm I just tried watching that variable and it becomes [{}] when valid, and null when invalid.... what is going on??? @.@)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you display is for the the key `url`. It thus signals that what you typed is an invalid URL, because your input is of type `url`. If you don't want angular to validate your input as a URL, make it of type text.

And if you want to display ERROR when the ng-pattern validation fails, use

```
ng-show="linkform.$error.pattern"
```

Also, if you want to only accept a, b, c and d inside the field, the pattern should be `/^[abcd]+$/`.

Comment: That doesn't explain the behaviour of showing an array of an empty object when valid and null when invalid. Regardless of the undefined behaviour, your suggestions are spot on. Apparently Angular won't let you specify a url type with your own pattern, but instead well fail silently by not working. yay...

Thanks again for your help, more arbitrary Angular knowledge acquired.